# Flutter Facebook Login Error: Getter not found: 'Success'. case FacebookLoginStatus.Success

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart, mobile, facebook-login

I am using Flutter to make my app and I wish to do function login with Facebook and this is what I did:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login_facebook/flutter_login_facebook.dart';

abstract class AuthBase {
  User get currentUser;

  Stream<User> authStateChanges();    

  Future<User> signInWithFacebook();

  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Stream<User> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  @override
  User get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

  @override
  Future<User> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final fb = FacebookLogin();
    final response = await fb.logIn(permissions: [
      FacebookPermission.publicProfile,
      FacebookPermission.email,
    ]);
    switch (response.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Success:
        final accessToken = response.accessToken;
        final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token),
        );
        return userCredential.user;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Cancel:
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
          message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
        );
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Error:
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAILED',
          message: response.error.developerMessage,
        );
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    await facebookLogin.logOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

And this is error I got:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
lib/services/auth.dart:68:32: Error: Getter not found: 'Success'.
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Success:
                               ^^^^^^^
lib/services/auth.dart:74:32: Error: Getter not found: 'Cancel'.
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Cancel:
                               ^^^^^^
lib/services/auth.dart:79:32: Error: Getter not found: 'Error'.
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Error:
                               ^^^^^
Restarted application in 278ms.
```

I tried to look at the tutorial and I see no difference in the code I wrote, it is on Udemy so I can not copy the link down here to you. Please tell me how to deal with that, thank you so much and have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change code to

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login_facebook/flutter_login_facebook.dart';

abstract class AuthBase {
  User get currentUser;

  Stream<User> authStateChanges();    

  Future<User> signInWithFacebook();

  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Stream<User> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  @override
  User get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

  @override
  Future<User> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final fb = FacebookLogin();
    final response = await fb.logIn(permissions: [
      FacebookPermission.publicProfile,
      FacebookPermission.email,
    ]);
    switch (response.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.success:
        final accessToken = response.accessToken;
        final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token),
        );
        return userCredential.user;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancel:
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
          message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
        );
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAILED',
          message: response.error.developerMessage,
        );
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    await facebookLogin.logOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

lower case this code:

```
case FacebookLoginStatus.Success:   to     case FacebookLoginStatus.success:
 case FacebookLoginStatus.Cancel:   to  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancel: 
 case FacebookLoginStatus.Error:   to  case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
```

Answer (score 0):

*Please try this snippet of* `code`, *It's working fine for me*.

```
  fbSignIn() async {
    var facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    var facebookLoginResult = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
    switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        print("Error");
        //showToast(msg: "A Error Occured");
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print("CancelledByUser");
        //showToast(msg: "Login Cancelled");
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        print(facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token);

        print("LoggedIn");
        break;
    }
  }
```